# Minify and variable names

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I know that minification is responsible for removing: white space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block delimiters. Not long ago I read it's also responsible for shorten variable names. But I always thought it's a part of obfuscation. Am I right? Or now minification libraries also include such functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, since the objective of minification is to reduce the size of the code as much as possible, renaming variables is an effective way of doing just that.

A trick that JavaScript minifiers often use, is to wrap the code in a immediately executed function, with a lot of arguments:

```
(function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){/* ... */})();
```

This makes it possible to use these variables without declaring them with the `var` keyword, thus reducing the size of your code by three bytes times the number of `var` keywords.

Modern minifiers use a lot of these advanced tricks to reduce the size of your code, that the code seems obfuscated is just a bi-product of the minification.

Comment: I wouldn't really say three bytes. Firstly "var " contains 4 characters counting the space. Secondly we'd also have to take "function" and the parentheses and everything into account. Lastly, in javascript we can declare multiple values without using the var keyword each time like this: var a,b,c; And that's shorter than the method you wrote. That being said, I haven't really ever looked into  minifiers.

Comment: Is there any way so that just by looking at the java script file, I can tell whether it has been minifiied or obfuscated or both? The problem is obfuscators also change variable names to reduce the file size e.g. temp becomes t. Minifiers are also employing this same technique these days. So that leaves me wondering what extra facility does an obfuscator provide?