# How to decrease the page load time when multiple css are used

Tags: javascript, html, css, pageload

How can i decrease the page load time when using multiple CSS and Javascript files.
In my website home page i have used about 6 javascript and 3 css files i know these many files can cause the page load to take time.

files which i used are :

js

`<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/respond.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>`

css

`<link href='css/style.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type='text/css' media="screen">`
 `<link href='css/reset.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type='text/css' media="screen">`
 `<link href='css/lightbox.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

How can i reduce the page load time without removing any files?.

Comment: Just combine them? Are they minified? Also, where are your `<script>` elements? You can usually move them to the end of the `<body>` (which is an improvement in several ways).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files

Comment: @minitech no they are not minified

Comment: use minified JS files.write all the css in single page instead of multiple files.

Comment: thank for the information i will minify CSS and JS and use them

Comment: @FlightOdyssey i checked out your link it had all the info i needed

Comment: After minify Gzip your CSS and JS file. this comparison will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196358/why-do-people-minify-css-and-javascript-when-we-have-gzip

Comment: @KheemaPandey wil Using Gzip in a responsive web site have any issues or problems?.

Comment: yahoo `Yslow` component suggest using gZip format for CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [jsCompressor](http://javascriptcompress.herokuapp.com/) to compress and minify multiple JavaScript files
and [CSS Compressor](http://javascriptcompress.herokuapp.com/css/) to compress/minify multiple Css files into one file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do other things as well like converting your links to base64 to reduce http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use W3 total cache plugin for wordpress and minify JS and CSS both from W3 Total Cache